# Where does the annotation send its output to in symfony php doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations

I was reading this tutorial

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-common/en/latest/reference/annotations.html#usage

They have code like this

```
<?php
namespace MyCompany\Entity;

use MyCompany\Annotations\Foo;
use MyCompany\Annotations\Bar;

/**
 * @Foo(bar="foo")
 * @Bar(foo="bar")
 */
class User
{
}
```

Now my main question is what will ahpen to `User` class with `foo` or `bar` annotation and where will that change will get reflected.

I am not able to understand when we use annotation then where do effect of annotations occur and at what point. I mean i want to know the difference between on `User` class before and after using annottaion

Comment: Annotations are used for mapping information as metadata in class file on properties and method of that class. It can be used to map class with table name in database, define datatype for properties in class, relation between the properties of different entites.

Comment: @basantrijal thats not 100% correct ... you can implement custom annotations as well and let them do what you want to do. So the Doctrine Annotations are mostly used for the database mapping thats correct.But there are some Annotations from Symfony itself to provide validation for instance (and many more).

Annotations need to be parsed.But there is no specific point inside the timeline from Request to Response where to do it. The implementation is decides.